# Howto set immutable field

Tags: java

```
  private static final Class<? extends UserManager> type;

  private static void setType(final Class <? extends UserManager> theType){
      if(type == null) type = theType;
      else throw new IllegalStateException("Type already set.");
  }
```

I want to get something like the above to work but it won't compile because `type` isn't `final` anyone know how to do this in Java? Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean to say `type` **is** `final`? If your intention is to make a field only settable once, just remove the `final` modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intrinsically impossible.
`final` means that you *cannot* change it after initialization is complete.

Comment: Bummer, I thought that `type` wouldn't have been initialized yet at this point because its still null.

Comment: Unfortunately you may change final fields using reflection.

Comment: @Howard: You can do anything using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

By default it is impossible, BUT using reflection :) all will be possible

```
      Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
      modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
      modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

      field.set(null, newValue);
```